# Function returns std::wstring = NULL;

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I have trying to make wrapper for winapi function `GetWindowText`.
Function returns std::wstring but i don't know how to handle where error happen. I return NULL but i know it's wrong.

```
std::wstring GetWindowText(HWND handle)
{
    const int size = 1024;
    TCHAR wnd_text[size] = {0};

    HRESULT hr = ::GetWindowText(handle,
                    wnd_text, size);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return std::wstring(wnd_text);
    else
        return NULL;    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to exceptions you could also return the string by reference in the argument list and indicate sucess by returning true or false i.e.

```
bool GetWindowText(HWND handle, std::wstring& windowText)
{
    const int size = 1024;
    TCHAR wnd_text[size] = {0};

    HRESULT hr = ::GetWindowText(handle,
                    wnd_text, size);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        windowText = wnd_text;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;    
}
```

Another alternative which avoids the reference argument is to return an instance of a class that wraps a value but also lets you know whether a value is present e.g.

```
class ValueWrapper
{
public:
    ValueWrapper() : present( false ) {}
    ValueWrapper( const std::wstring& s ) : value( s ), present( true ) {}

    bool isPresent() const { return present; }
    const std::wstring& getValue() const { return value; }

private:
    std::wstring value;
    bool present;
};
```

Note that you can template this wrapper pretty easily. Your function would then be

```
ValueWrapper GetWindowText(HWND handle)
{
    const int size = 1024;
    TCHAR wnd_text[size] = {0};

    HRESULT hr = ::GetWindowText(handle,
                    wnd_text, size);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return ValueWrapper( wnd_text );
    else
        return ValueWrapper();
}
```

Comment: Note that [`boost::optional<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) is a preexisting, tested implementation of `ValueWrapper`.

Comment: Note that `boost::optional<>` has a name that is misleading in this case---the conventional name here is `Fallible`.  (Also, it's possible to extend a `Fallible` so that it contains additional information concerning the error.)

Answer (score 7):

Throw an [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) instead.

```
std::wstring GetWindowText(HWND handle)
{
    const int size = 1024;
    TCHAR wnd_text[size] = {0};

    HRESULT hr = ::GetWindowText(handle,
                    wnd_text, size);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return std::wstring(wnd_text);
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("insert error message here");    
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is good Idea. Generaly winapi functions doesn't throw exceptions. It is better to set last error via `SetLastError()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Mihran: this is a *C++* wrapper, so it's correct that it converts WinAPI idioms in C++ idioms. It would be even better if it encapsulated `GetLastError` value in a particular exception type.

Comment: In this case, he still has to return a value. What value should it be? Also, calling `GetLastError` after each call to this function is way uglier than just catching an exception.

Comment: I'd factor out the code to generate an error message from the failure code, but throwing an exception in response to an error case is *exactly* correct (given that it's not the OS interface itself which is doing this; there are some very good reasons for OSes to not throw exceptions themselves).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution (without throwing exceptions): use the [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is definitely **not** ok for strings, you are specifically not allowed to pass a null pointer to the string constructor.

If you don't want to throw an exception, you can return the empty string, `return std::wstring();`.

Comment: But if the string in question is actually empty, it will lead to a fake error.

Comment: @Grigory - It might, yes, depending on what the interface is defined to be. However, std::wstring(NULL) is **always** an error as it violates the language standard!

Answer (score 0):

WinApi designed so that it never throws exception. And to get reason of some unsuccessfull return of some function you in most cases have to get last error via [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As I understand your function is going to be some addition to WinApi which will be easy to use. So I suggest keep their design as well. i.e. In case of failure return empty string and check what is last error if your function returns it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all GetWindowText() does not return HRESULT so your code is just wrong in this respect.

And second, GetWindowTextW returns 0 on any error or number of characters if OK.
So just return an empty string:

```
std::wstring GetWindowText(HWND handle)
{
    const int size = 1024;
    TCHAR wnd_text[size] = {0};

    INT n = ::GetWindowTextW(handle,
                    wnd_text, size);
    if(n > 0)
        return std::wstring(wnd_text,n);
    else
        return std::wstring();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, there are several appropriate
solutions.  The first is to throw an exception in case of an
error: if you go this route, you should define a WindowsError
exception (deriving from one of the standard exceptions), which
includes all of the information available from `GetLastError`,
and possibly additional information (name of the function which
failed, etc.), in an easy to parse format.  The other is to
return some sort of `Fallible`; in this case, you may want to
extend the classical `Fallible` idiom so that it can contain
additional information concerning the cause of the error.  Still
another possibility is to return the value via an out parameter,
and use a return code (again, possibly with additional
information, and possibly with added code to ensure that it has
been tested before being destructed).